# html form inside a box?

Tags: html, forms, textbox, border

I would like to put a form inside a box, or have a border around a form but I got stuck. The background has to be white and I was thinking that perhaps a transparent option was ok. Any expert out there that has some simple idea how to solve it?
Enclosing some code. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emrtg91n/)

[What I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHDKl.png)

```
<body>
<div id="border"></div>
<div id="text">Auf dem tisch</div>
</body>

body {background: white;}

#border {
        border: 2px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        margin-center: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background: navy;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

#text   {
        margin-center: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <div class="box">
<form>
..
..
</form>
</div>

// css style to make border in center of the form

.box{
margin:0 auto; 
width:600px //you can set it in %.
padding:20px;
background:#f9f9f9;
border:2px solid #333;
}
```